# Serial port responder buffer null issue C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to make a small Console program in C# which mimics a hardware where the it responses a particular sent command in a master slave fashion. So another program(master) will send a byte array for example: 0xFF, 0x00, 0xCD, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00; and the slave Console program I try to make will check this received byte array and if its third element is 0xCD then it will respond as  0xFF, 0x00, 0xCD, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00.

Here is the entire program I tried:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace ConsoleMyConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort();

            byte[] message_to_receive = null;
            byte[] message_to_response = { 0xFF, 0x00, 0xCD, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            myPort.PortName = "COM8";
            myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            myPort.DataBits = 8;
            myPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            myPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            myPort.Open();

            int received_bytes = myPort.BytesToRead;
            myPort.Read(message_to_receive, 0, received_bytes);

            if (message_to_receive[2] == 0xCD)
                myPort.Write(message_to_response, 0, message_to_response.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this program I get: **System.ArgumentNullException: 'Buffer cannot be null** error. I dont know why is this happening at myPort.Read. I have to declare message_to_receive anyway, and couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this specification page.
[SerialPort.Read Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

For the buffer array specified in the parameter of the Read(), an area of the size required by the calling application must be prepared in advance.
Unlike ReadExisting(), ReadLine(), and ReadTo(), the API does not prepare the character string data.

Prepare an array with the longest data size that can occur, or prepare an array with a short size and repeat Read() as many times as necessary.

Comment: So if my slave port is expecting a byte array size of 10 does that mean I should declare byte[] telegram_received = new byte[10]; ? If not please give a code example otherwise by reading cannot picture it.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do it that way.

Comment: Can it also be greater than expected size like new byte[120]? Or should it be the exact size with the expected array's?

Comment: It is also possible to prepare a buffer that is larger than the received data. However, if you specify the entire buffer size with Read(), Read() will not end until you receive data of that size or an error such as a timeout occurs. The size you receive is unpredictable unless it is determined by the protocol. Also, because of asynchronous communication, depending on the protocol, multiple notifications may be read together with one Read(), or one response may be split into multiple Read().